# Pagination detection selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to detect the number of the total pages .. so as to deal with all the pages and here's my attempt

```
Sub Test()
    Dim bot As New WebDriver, ele As WebElement, sURL As String, x As Long
    sURL = "https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/obbligazioni/titoli-di-stato/btp/1"
    bot.Start "Chrome", sURL
    bot.Get sURL
    '//*[@id="r_pagingArea"]/div/a[5]
    Set ele = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='r_pagingArea']/div/a[5]")
    For x = 1 To 10
        If ele.IsDisplayed Then
            Debug.Print "Page " & x
            ele.Click
            bot.ExecuteScript "window.focus();"
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    MsgBox "Total of " & x & " Pages"
End Sub
```

After the first page it goes to the next page but got an error after that as for the ele variable

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different approach and get the number of pages from

```
Dim numPages As Long
numPages = bot.FindElementsByCss("[href^='./']").count
```

Then do a loop from `For i = 2 to numPages`, and simply

```
bot.get "https://mercati.ilsole24ore.com/obbligazioni/titoli-di-stato/btp/" & i
```

I would avoid using your `ele` being set outside of loop as element may become stale after click event.